# autoconf directive to change 'objdir'

Tags: libtool

Need a way to instruct autoconf to store the C++ libraries to a different path than the default '.libs'

Currently all the objects seems to get stored at 'src/.libs/' , while would like that to be stored at 'src/.libs/x86_64-linux-gcc/' as these are 64bit objects.

Answer (score 0):

First, this isn't Autoconf doing that, but Libtool.

I don't think there is good support for what you appear to be trying to do.

The autotools way is to build for different targets in different object trees.  Therefore, there will be no confusion about what target a file under `.libs` is for.